# Problem with plotting a function with NIntegrate

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

Why does the following `Plot3D` command never terminate?

```
m=0.8;i=5.6;w=100*Pi;
vma[t_, v0_] := m Sin[w t] + v0;
vmb[t_, v0_] := m Sin[w t-2*Pi/3] + v0;
vmc[t_, v0_] := m Sin[w t+2*Pi/3] + v0;
ia[t_, theta_] := i Sin[w t + theta];
ib[t_, theta_] := i Sin[w t + theta-2*Pi/3];
ic[t_, theta_] := i Sin[w t + theta+2*Pi/3];
in[t_, theta_,v0_] := -(Sign[vma[t, v0]] vma[t, v0] ia[t, theta] + 
  Sign[vmb[t, v0]] vmb[t, v0] ib[t, theta] + 
  Sign[vmc[t, v0]] vmc[t, v0] ic[t, theta]);
vc1[theta_?NumericQ, v0_?NumericQ] := 280 + 1/(2*4700*^-6) * 
  NIntegrate[in[t, theta, v0], {t, 0, 0.3}];
Plot3D[vc1[theta,v0], {theta,-Pi, Pi}, {v0, -0.2, 0.2}]
```

Answer (score 3):

First, I don't know anything about this particular function and I've not examined the definitions closely at all.  If you simply try to execute something like `vc1[0.1,0.1]`, though, you'll find that it takes 3 or 4 seconds to evaluate.  `vc1[0,0]` throws errors, so these things need to be more efficient.  I simply changed your definition of `vc1` to include some standard tricks to speed up the integration.

```
vc1[theta_?NumericQ, v0_?NumericQ] := 280 + 1/(2*4700*^-6) *
  NIntegrate[in[t, theta, v0], {t, 0, 0.3}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 5, AccuracyGoal -> 3,
  Method->{"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing"->0}];
```

Note that the decrease of `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` may be problematic for some applications, but this level of precision cannot be discerned in a plot anyway.

Now, we can also tone the expectations of `Plot3D` down a bit be decreasing `PlotPoints` and setting `MaxRecursion` to zero.  The following now takes about 8 seconds on my machine.

```
Plot3D[vc1[theta, v0], {theta, -Pi, Pi}, {v0, -0.2, 0.2},
  MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 15]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks,the result is consistent with MATLAB,but using mathematica is easier,I think.